# Rails 4: Advanced Query for Search Interface

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, where-clause

I need to perform a query on my model that allows me to test an array of tags (`belongs_to :recipe`)

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :recipes, through: :taggings
end
```

It works when I do:

```
Recipe.joins(:tags).where("tags.name = ?", 'main course')
```

but I want to test an array of tags.  If I don't use `join` I can query using an array as follows:

```
Recipe.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

but it fails when I try:

```
Recipe.joins(:tags).where(tags.name: ['main course', 'snack'])
```

**How do I fix that final query (postgres db) to allow for an array?**

Comment: You can't write arbitrary SQL expressions like `tags.name` in Ruby. Those need to be written as strings.

Answer (score 2):

`Recipe.where(id: [1, 2, 3])` will use `in` because array of ids are passed.

To make it work with tags.name,

```
Recipe.joins(:tags).where('tags.name in (?) ', ['main course', 'snack'])
```

should be used as we are searching from joined relation and not from recipes table.

Comment: Prefer `.where('tags.name' => ['main course', 'snack'])` and let Rails build the `where ... in (...)` for you.

Comment: I noticed a problem.  I need this to only return recipes with ALL tags in the array, not any recipes with ANY of the tags in the array.  In other words the above example should only return recipes tagged with main course AND snack